# Move Jar file to Start Up Folder

Tags: java, jar

How do u move a Jar file to the Start up folder with code? Like within the code either make a Jar file or move it to a different directory with Java.

Edit: So basicly i have a Jar file on the Desktop, I want to move the Jar file to or duplicate the jar file and move that to lets say C:\Program Files (x86) When u run the Jar File

Comment: can you please be more elaborative with your question, so that we can help.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible for a program to move itself while executing, my instinct tells me that the file system wouldn't be able to get a lock on the archive.

Comment: Would it be possible to make another applet that just move that applet... That might make it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but if I remember correctly you want something along the lines of:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp path/to/jar path/to/destination");
```

Where the string is the appropriate terminal command for your OS and what you want to do. Different methods surely exist, however I believe this is the easiest way. Here are some example commands:

**Copying files**:

Windows: `cp path\to\jar destination\path`

Linux:   `cp path/to/jar destination/path` (note: you may need to prefix this command with `sudo` if the logged in user doesn't have the proper permissions. This can introduce its own headaches, so tread lightly)

**Making a JAR archive**:

Windows:  `jar cf path\to\jar path\to\files`

Linux:    `jar cf path/to/jar path/to/files` (again, it is possible you may need the `sudo` prefix)

Comment: So right now im using two diferent applets one runs: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/IRCBot.jar C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/Games/"); However that is not working

Comment: Im getting Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cp": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Comment: Try "xcopy" on windows, instead of "cp".